# Unresolved constraint in bundle with Java 8 and Felix

Tags: java, tomcat, java-8, tomcat6, apache-felix

I have an app running under Tomcat 6. The app contains/uses shared library, say Shared.jar. At some point it would copy Shared.jar with unique name, load it as an OSGi bundle into a Felix instance, and start it. In Shared.jar MANIFEST.MF there's

`Import-Package: org.osgi.framework,javax.swing,javax.net,javax.net.ssl`.

It's all fine with Java < 8, but with Java 8 the app itself starts fine, but starting a bundle fails with exception

`Unresolved constraint in bundle [21431]: Unable to resolve 21431.0: missing requirement [21431.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.net)`

What's wrong?

Comment: How do you build your application? Is it with Maven? If so, can you share the `pom.xml`?

Comment: @kocko No, it's just Eclipse projects. I've updated my question, it's actually more complicated, sorry for providing incorrect info first.

Comment: I am not asking about the IDE, I'm asking how do you build the application? I assume this error appears during the build process and the root cause of the problem is some incorrect setting of the classpath. So, is there something like a `pom.xml` in the project?

Comment: @kocko I hit build in Eclipse, or with ant. This is a very old code, Maven wasn't very popular back then, I believe. As I explained in the updated question, the exception is thrown when I'm starting a bundle loaded into Felix. In general, are there any changes in Java 8 that could cause such errors about base packages like javax.net?

Comment: Do you have rt.jar included in your build path of your project?

Answer (score 0):

You need minimum Karaf 2.4 to support Java 8.

May be you would also need to add import package declaration in your pom.xml

```
<Import-Package>javax.net.*</Import-Package>
```

..but that doesn't look like the main issue, because it is working with older versions of JRE.

Comment: I'm not using neither Karaf, nor Maven.